# Why losing apetite is always a criteria when stomach pain happens

Tags: stomach, health-education, loss-of-appetite, endoscopy

Why when a patient feels a pain in his stomach, doctors always ask him if he's losing apetite ?

What does losing apetite conduct to as diagnosis ?

Comment: There isn't a one-for-one mapping from question to diagnosis. Loss of appetite is just one data point among many that a doctor considers to form a diagnosis. So there really isn't a way to answer your question.